# What is the MySQL network compression algorithm

Tags: mysql, algorithm, compression, protocols

Our company is dealing with a hardware supplied by another company, which no longer exists, and support is non existant. We decided to create application that mimics what their system does, and it involves sending MySQL Queries and analyzing the responses. I have a lot of pcap captured traffic of the MySQL communicaton, but unfortunately beyond the first query - the responses, and subsequent queries are all compressed until the Quit command. I am pretty sure there is no SSL involved. So I am looking for a way to even manually decompress the network packets payload, only I do not know the compression algorithm, and can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL manual suggests it is Zlib

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/zlib-directory.html

> zlib is a data compression library used to support the compressed
>   protocol and the COMPRESS/UNCOMPRESS functions under Windows. On Unix,
>   MySQL uses the system libgz.a library for this purpose.

From http://zlib.net/

> the compression algorithm used in zlib is essentially the same as that in  > gzip and Zip, namely, the `deflate' method that originated in PKWARE's
>   PKZIP 2.x.

Comment: Thank you! I also found out that it's ZLIB, and even wrote decompression routine to check that it is correct. I am accepting your answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

According to Java connector source code it's zip deflated. You can find uncompressing code here

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/5.1/src/com/mysql/jdbc/CompressedInputStream.java